# Can I connect to my local SQL Server 2008 R2 from another computer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 on my computer and my ASP.NET MVC 4 project connects to it via a connection string. If I keep my computer running, how can I modify the connection string so that another developer/computer working on the same project also connect with the database?

Comment: Working where? Are the computers connected by a local network?

Comment: @Claudio not connected by a local network. Working remotely.

Comment: You need a couple of things: 1) Enable remote connections (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191464(v=sql.105).aspx) 2) Be sure the port used by sql is open to outside world (or at least for your working partner) 3) Your partner will need to use the public ip address on `Data Source` part of the connection string.

Comment: 4) You'll probably need to configure portforwarding or some mechanism to redirect request to the sql server port to the correct machine